# Why does Jquery :odd selector select even elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
 <head> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $("p:odd").html('pawned');
    });
   </script>
 </head>
<body>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Output -

```
1
pawned
3
pawned
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it utilizes 0-based indexing.

`1` is the 0 index (which is even) and so forth.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)

Arrays are 0-based in JS, and jQuery objects wrap elements in an array-like structure. Naturally, most jQuery methods utilize 0-based indexing unless explicitly stated otherwise - as [`nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), which is 1-indexed due to being strictly derived from the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Answer (score 4):

`"In particular, note that the 0-based indexing means that, counter-intuitively, :odd selects the second element, fourth element, and so on within the matched set."`

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

Index Starts with 0. Hence the result
Read this: http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/